# Active Directory Users Delegated Permissions

Tags: active-directory, permissions, directory, users, delegation

This is probably a dumb question, but how does the delegated user access ad to make these changes? I have set this up but a user cannot launch the active directory users and groups tool. Only admins can. Do I have to make the delgated user an admin on the computer running the tool?

Example: if i delegate the right to unlock a user account to a helpdesk user, how does this helpdesk user access the user account to actually unlock it?

**Solved by using "Account Lockout and Management Tools".**

Comment: The Active Directory Users & Computers snap-in shouldn't require admin privileges to simply launch. If it is, something is misconfigured. Do they simply not see the shortcut? Or are you actually getting an Access Denied or UAC elevation prompt?

Comment: Yeah, I was unable to locate ADUC on the workstation, but I used the "Account Lockout and Management Tools", problem solved. Thanks for the comments guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Start the ADUC, find your domain tree and browse to the topmost level that you with to apply user permissions

At the users or Group dialog clock the "Add" button... You will be prompted to add a user or group

At the Select User.... dialog type the name of the object or clock "Advanced".. like you wish..

Than: Delegate your task to User Objects and give your object the permissions to Change Passwort, Reset Passwort, Read userAccountControl, Write userAccountControl..

You're done.

Comment: I had already done this, it was just that I could not find how to unlock the users from a workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all your posts above, you really need to re-phrase your question. It should say "how do I install  ADUC on windows 7", or something similar.

To answer your question, you need to install RSAT, then enable the feature under ADDS. Google "RSAT windows 7" then you will find it.